# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at HTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, flask

It's a simple application using flask framework which takes in the name of the user and then presents two options as buttons to the user. I am using javascript on the frontend and used handlebar template system here. After receiving the username later when I click on the dice option button it doesn't do anything in response. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. The error says : app.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
at HTMLDocument. (app.js:23

My javascript file

```
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#wel').innerHTML)
const dicetemp = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#dice').innerHTML)
let count = 0
let total = 0
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function(){
                    const name = document.querySelector("#name").value
                    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
                    request.open('POST', '/home')
                    request.onload = function(){
                        const data = request.responseText
                        const content = template({'value': data})
                        document.querySelector('#welcome').innerHTML = content

                    }
                    const data = new FormData()
                    data.append("name",name)
                    request.send(data)
                    document.querySelector("#form").remove()
                    document.title = 'My Games Portal'
                    return false
                }
                document.querySelector('#dicebtn').onclick = function(){
                    const content = dicetemp()
                    document.querySelector('#diceelement').innerHTML = content
                }
            })
```

Comment: Looks like your code compiles those templates but does not actually add them to the DOM.

Comment: the first template is working. Second One is not working..it should have generated when i click the button having id = dicebtn

Comment: Right, but that means that `document.querySelector('#button')` happens **before** that exists in the DOM.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Found the solution. Understood your direction and moved the last section of the javasript code inside the eventlistner function. Thanks. It works now.